# Flutter Blue Thermal Printer Library stuck

Tags: flutter, printing, bluetooth, android-permissions

I have created a page to connect to a bluetooth printer with Blue Thermal Printer 1.2.3.
On load to the page, it will called getBondedDevices().

On the first load, when call to this function, it will prompt for permission.
After allow the permission, the page is stuck.
I will need to reload to this page, then it can go smoothly.

The page will only go smoothly if no prompt for permission.

Exception message:

```
I/FactoryLoader(22605): loadFactory() ClassNotFoundException !
2
I/ClientTransactionHandler(22605): send EXECUTE_TRANSACTION
E/RtgSchedIpcFile(22605): RtgSchedIpcFile failed to open /proc/22605/rtg
I/RmeSchedManager(22605): init Rme, version is: v1.0
E/RtgSchedIpcFile(22605): setCommandByIoctl not opened
D/RtgSched(22605): resetRtgSchedHandle failed enable:0
I/ViewRootImpl(22605): focus window changed, set pointer icon to default
D/DecorView(22605): showOrHideHighlightView: hasFocus=false; winMode=1; isMrgNull=true
I/ClientTransactionHandler(22605): send EXECUTE_TRANSACTION
D/ActivityThread(22605): Won't deliver top position change in state=4
E/RtgSchedIpcFile(22605): RtgSchedIpcFile failed to open /proc/22605/rtg
I/RmeSchedManager(22605): init Rme, version is: v1.0
E/RtgSchedIpcFile(22605): setCommandByIoctl not opened
D/RtgSched(22605): resetRtgSchedHandle failed enable:1
I/ClientTransactionHandler(22605): send EXECUTE_TRANSACTION
I/DecorView[](22605): set decor visibility 0
I/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](22605): controlInsetsForCompatibility not hide statusbar
D/DecorView(22605): showOrHideHighlightView: hasFocus=true; winMode=1; isMrgNull=true
W/InputMethodManager(22605): startInputReason = 1
```

Original Code from library:

```
Future<List<BluetoothDevice>> getBondedDevices() async {
  final List list = await (_channel.invokeMethod('getBondedDevices'));
  return list.map((map) => BluetoothDevice.fromMap(map)).toList();
}
```

I have tried to find the problem line by line, and I found that it will stuck in this line.

```
final List list = await (_channel.invokeMethod('getBondedDevices'));
```